# Buffer Is Not Defined in Javascript

Tags: javascript, encode

I am trying to encode `vm.getInput.path` to base64 by using the following code. The problem is that I am getting the error that Buffer is not defined.

```
function get() {
    resetResults();
    RetrieveObjects.resource.get( 
        {
            chain: vm.getInput.chain,
            dataCenter: vm.getInput.dataCenter,
            path: Buffer.from(vm.getInput.path).toString('base64')
        },
        function successCallback(response) {
            vm.result = response.getResult;
            console.log(response)
        },
        function errorCallback(response) {
            vm.error = response;
        }
    );
}
```

**Error**

```
angular.js:13294 ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined
    at RetrieveObjects.get (RetrieveObjects.controller.js:64:27)
    at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:14138:15), <anonymous>:4:253)
    at expensiveCheckFn (angular.js:15151:18)
    at callback (angular.js:24674:17)
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:16895:28)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:16995:25)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:24679:23)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery.js:4737:27)
    at elemData.handle (jquery.js:4549:28)
```

I don't know how to solve that issue. Second time in my life I use Javascript.

Comment: I don't think browsers implement Buffer? You might be trying to use node specific JavaScript in the browser. I make this assumption as the error includes jQuery

Comment: @evolutionxbox really? Sheesh. What Can I use instead, It's not allowing me to use btoa, Claiming its deprecated

Comment: What is claiming atob is deprecated? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/atob

Comment: ```The signature '(data: string): string' of 'btoa' is deprecated.ts(6387)
buffer.d.ts(2230, 12): The declaration was marked as deprecated here.

Comment: @HaniGotc Perhaps the globally scoped `btoa` is, but you can use `window.btoa`

Comment: It's deprecated in node, but not in the browser. By using `window.btoa` typescript understands you're specifically going for the browser implementation.

Comment: sheesh well that's great then. Thaank uuuuu

Comment: @HaniGotc same goes for setTimeout etc. if you don't prefix it with `window.`, Typescript pulls it from the ScriptHost (Node) library instead of DOM

Comment: If you really want to suffer, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextEncoder and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Base64#solution_2_%E2%80%93_rewriting_atob_and_btoa_using_typedarrays_and_utf-8 probably can be mangled into doing what you need.

Comment: Naa I don't want to suffer. I think btoa is such a beautiful function. Yes I saw that earlier. I cried. @tevemadar

Comment: @DustInComp You should just declare `"lib": "dom"` in your typescript config, and it should not pull *anything* from the nodejs definitions

Comment: @Bergi I would if I wasn't also using the Node environment during the build step, so I end up including both.

Comment: @DustInComp One shouldn't use the `"node"` environment when building frontend code